# Can latest version of mongo db connector can be used with loopback@2.26.2

Tags: node.js, mongodb, loopbackjs

We have an application, in which we are using loopback@2.26.2. However, we are facing lot of issues w.r.t mongodb connections, replica set failures and so on. But we don't want the loopback version to upgrade because of some internal reason. 
Can we just upgrade the mongo drivers such as loopback-connector-mongodb and mongodb to latest version without upgrading the loopback version.

We are using node version 4.4.0 and Mongo DB replica set version 3.6

```
npm list|grep loopback
├─┬ allcountjs-loopback@1.0.6
├─┬ loopback@2.26.2
│ ├── loopback-connector-remote@1.3.3
│ ├─┬ loopback-phase@1.4.1
├─┬ loopback-boot@2.16.0
├─┬ loopback-component-explorer@2.3.0
│ ├─┬ loopback-swagger@2.9.0
├─┬ loopback-component-storage@1.7.0
├── loopback-connector@2.3.0
├─┬ loopback-connector-mongodb@1.13.3
├─┬ loopback-datasource-juggler@2.45.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm late, but I want to share that we faced similar problems and the finding is:

[mongodb nodejs driver](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongodb)(sub-dependency of loopback-connector-mongodb) starting on version 3.3.0, needs that MongoDB engine to be at least in version 4.2 (in clusters). We had MongoDB at 4.0.4 and mongodb nodejs driver at 3.3.2 after an NPM packages update and our app was unable to do any update or upsert. This was the error:

> MongoError: Transaction numbers are only allowed on a replica set
>   member or mongos\n

Our solution was to update MongoDB engine version to 4.2.